# Responsive design - Change layout with javascript and css (flex and media-queries)

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, flexbox

Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/mrcjcfe7/19/ for a working layout.

I have 3 columns (COL1, COL2 and COL3) I need to rearrange depending of screen width. The twist is I need to get COL3 under COL2 when the screen is between 300-600px. Under 300px, I need to show COL2, COL3 and COL1.

When the screen is resized, the combination of CSS and Javascript makes the job.

```js
var col1 = document.getElementById('col1'),
    col2 = document.getElementById('col2'),
    swapped = false;

window.onresize = function () {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width < 300 && swapped === false) {
        swapCols();
        swapped = true;
    } else if (width > 300 && swapped === true) {
        swapCols();
        swapped = false;
    }
};

function swapCols() {
    var _col1 = col1.innerHTML,
        _col1id = col1.id,
        _col2 = col2.innerHTML,
        _col2id = col2.id;
    col1.innerHTML = _col2;
    col1.id = _col2id;
    col2.innerHTML = _col1;
    col2.id = _col1id;
}
```

```css
html * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    background:#000;
    font-family:helvetica, verdana;
}
#wrapper {
    width:600px;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background:#cc4444;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background:#44cc44;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background:#4444cc;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width:600px) {
    #col3 {
        float:none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:300px) {
    #wrapper {
        width:100%;
    }
    #col1, #col2, #col3 {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="col1" class="cols">COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 -</div>
    <div id="col2" class="cols">COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 -</div>
    <div id="col3" class="cols">COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 -</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is when COL2 contains more stuff then COL1. COL3 takes the place I want but there is a gap filling the space beside COL2. Edit : Please take a look at the image at the end of this post.

How can I achieve the desired layout without the gap when the screen is between 300-600px and the second column contains more stuff than the first one?

Thank you,

Sebastien

EDIT
[Here is an image showing the correct layout and the problem I attempt to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJWym.png)

Comment: So I'm a bit confused...you have 3 columns (COL1 COL2 COL3). When the screen in between 300px-600px, you want COL3 to be below COL2? And when the screen is below 300px, show the columns in order, so COL1, then COL2 under that? with COL3 under COL2?

Comment: Try flex with `order` property.

Comment: That's right, as @mwl says try `flex` layout: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I tried flex and I get relatively the same results (https://jsfiddle.net/n9bt0x0e/1/) When the screen is between 400 to 600px, the line wraps (COL1 beside COL2 and COL3 on a "new" line). I need COL3's content to be right under COL1's content. Seems like to fill the gap between COL1 and COL3 would require a merge of the two columns content.

Comment: is something like this you are looking for? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfgdb5nq/)

Comment: Thanks @dippas but it still doesn't solve the problem. I updated your sample http://jsfiddle.net/xfgdb5nq/1/ Take a look when COL1 contains **less** stuff than COL2. When COL3 wraps, there is a gap between COL1 and COL3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help. I finally got something working for this 3 columns responsive layout.

I now use [flex](/questions/tagged/flex) for the basis layout with a combination of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to solve the original question.

1. When there is not enough space, the third column wraps under the first one with [flex-flow](/questions/tagged/flex-flow): **row wrap**;.
2. When the first column contains less stuff then the second one (my original question), I use [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to **swap** the third colunm with an empty div at the bottom of the first column. This way, there is no gap under the first column when the third one wraps.
3. Finally, I use [media-queries](/questions/tagged/media-queries) with [flex](/questions/tagged/flex) **order** to place the second column in first position when the columns are one above the other.

Here is a working sample. **Note when you run the code snippet** : You must shrink the width of your browser to see the columns adjust.

```js
var col1 = document.getElementById('sc1'),
    col2 = document.getElementById('c3'),
    swapped = false;

window.onresize = function () {
    detectSwap();
};

window.onload = function () {
    detectSwap();
};

function detectSwap() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width <= 599 && swapped === false) {
        swapCols();
        swapped = true;
    } else if (width > 599 && swapped === true) {
        swapCols();
        swapped = false;
    }
}

function swapCols() {
    var _col1 = col1.innerHTML,
        _col1id = col1.id,
        _col2 = col2.innerHTML,
        _col2id = col2.id;
    col1.innerHTML = _col2;
    col1.id = _col2id;
    col2.innerHTML = _col1;
    col2.id = _col1id;
}
```

```css
html * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.cols {
    width: 200px;
}
#c1 {
    background:#cc4444;
}
#c2 {
    background:#44cc44;
}
#c3 {
    background:#4444cc;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    #c1 {
        order: 2;
    }
    #c2 {
        order: -1;
    }
    #c3 {
        order: 3;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div id="c1" class="cols">COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 - COL 1 -
        <div id="sc1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="c2" class="cols">COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 - COL 2 -</div>
    <div id="c3" class="cols">COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3 -COL 3 - COL 3 - COL 3</div>
</div>
```